# Disable screenshot in flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin

How to disable screenshot in flutter? I have Kotlin file instead of MainActivity.java file. Please suggest full code with path where I need to change for disable screenshot in my app.

```
package com.quotster.untitled

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

}
```

Comment: That is an android native capability.  It's currently not possible in flutter.   You should post this in an android native section.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in Android only you can use [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) and add `FLAG_SECURE`.

```
await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
```